# Sleep mode on MacPro not working after installing a Cinema Display

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-pro, cinema-display

I am not sure I can connect the two events, but ever since I connected a Cinema display to my 2009 Mac Pro it seems like it is not entering sleep mode after the indicated time has passed. It will Sleep just fine if I use the apple menu command.

I've searched the usual news groups and other apple web sites and while I've seen a lot of speculation I've not seen a solution. I tried turning off all sharing on this computer (which was one of the more promising tips) and that didn't do the trick.

Any suggestions from those wiser than I would be great!

Comment: Have you tested if disconnecting the Cinema display allows the Mac to go to sleep after a set time?

Comment: Which cinema display do you have, is it ADC? Can you unplug its USB from the Mac Pro and see if it will go into sleep mode?

Comment: What's ADC? It's the 27" non-thunderbolt version.

Comment: Yes I have the ADC. And I just tried it without the USB and it still doesn't sleep. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!